# How to add edge in a cylinder so that only the end can be scaled?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

How can I split the cylinder so that I can scale only the end of the cylinder, like in the bottom image. (Not to scale all of the cylinder.)

What I have now:
[image: current cylinder]

I want it as such:
[image: desired result]

Comment: What you are looking for is loop cut Ctrl-R

Answer (score 6):

You can either add a loop cut, or cut the cylinder with the knife tool, or move your current end and extrude another edge to make it longer.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for adding a [loopcut](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html).

To add a loop cut simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> (to confirm the count of one new edge) then move the edge down to the end and <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> again to confirm the spot.

[image: animated gif showing how to add a loop cut]

---

<kbd>K</kbd> is for the [knife tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html).

To use the knife tool you are going to want to press 
<kbd>Z</kbd> after you started the knife tool, to enable "Cut through." Then after you made the cut press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to confirm and leave the knife tool.

[image: animated gif showing usage of the knife tool]

---

To extrude a new edge, first select your current end now press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> for the [edge slide tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-slide), move the end to where the taper starts.

A little trick to get the new extrusion along the same normal, press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face. From that face blender will be able to continue the next extrusion along the exact same angle.

Now press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude a new edge, simply <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> when it is in the correct spot.

[image: animated gif showing moving the end then extruding a new edge]